# how to refresh the elements in a adapter without starting a new activity?

Tags: android

I have the following situation:
I have a singleton controller which contains a `List<Foo>`

when my activity starts I load the items to my BaseExpandableListAdapter

the problem: When I now delete a item form the singleton List it gets net deletet in the view. Only when I start the whole activity again. **How to solve this without starting the whole activity again?**

Comment: i use contextual menu to delete the data from list, after deleting i  getIntent(), finish() and again startActivity() using the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public void notifyDataSetChanged ()
Added in API level 1

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Answer (score 1):

When you change the database that is used by the adapter, you should call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter.